# Reading result of an sql count with javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I am fairly new to javascript, and this is my first project involving sql. I'm making an ordering system, and i'm populating an order form based on an sql inventory database. I've figured out how to import the product descriptions, and how to change the number of inputs based on how many rows, but I don't know how to read the result of a SELECT count() with javascript, and use that to set the number of inputs. I'm also not sure if I'm doing this entire thing efficiently in the first place, so if anybody's willing to pm me for more details and help me streamline it, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: You need to post some code, show us what you've done so far

Comment: I have no idea why this was upvoted. At this point it is lacking any kind of detail needed to be a good question.

Comment: Generally speaking, you have to transfer your data from the server-side (database) to the client-side (browser) in a structured format such as JSON or XML. Then you can use `JSON.parse()` or some js library with parsing functionality to turn your data in JavaScript objects and do what you will with them. But it's hard to give helpful specifics if you dont go into more detail and/or share your existing code.

Comment: i'm sorry. I know most of the time these forum posts have code, but i'm in the developement stage. I have no code for this portion, because I have no clue where to even begin. I'm not even really looking for specifics, though, more just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: don't get hung up on the reading of the COUNT() specifically. JS (in a browser) can't read your database directly anyway. It can just read a value as the result of a HTTP request to the server. It doesn't know or care if it originated from a database or not. You need a server-side language/framework to respond to the HTTP request, query the DB and return the response as HTML, JSON, XML or whatever. Popular languages include PHP or ASP.NET (C#/VB) or Perl or Ruby etc etc. Unless you're talking about server-side nodeJS already?

Comment: ADyson, that's exactly what I was thinking. I'm going to use PHP to query the DB, but you're saying I need the PHP script to set up the HTML return? And then I should be able to use that return with JS? If so, that makes complete sense.